# Creating Remote database in Android

Tags: android

This is my first post in stackoverflow.
I am beginner in Android app development and trying to make an app with Signup screen with username and email-id.

1.I want to store these details at some remote database so that user can also login from "other" android device and thus SQlite can't be used for the purpose.

How can i accomplish this ?

2.Suppose i have a website and want to use the website's database to authenticate and register clients via login/Signup.

What are possible ways to do this ?

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Rohit, welcome to Stack Overflow.  You might want to have a look at the site [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and see how you can better refine your question so that you get useful answers.  As it stands, your question is far too general, and amounts to a "help me design my project" type inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some web services for your connection to remote database. For example you can make a sign up request via your web service. Your web service can talk to your remote database and returns a response to you. You can use this response in your application. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ACengiz and a good service to test with is Google fusion tables. You can find various samples on the web, this is a good start: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/java